# How to perform group aggregation in MySQL, without nested queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_TRANSACTIONS (
  START_TIME        BIGINT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
  APPLICATION_ID    CHAR(64) BINARY  NOT NULL,
  ENTRY_POINT       CHAR(255) BINARY NOT NULL,
  USER_ID           CHAR(64) BINARY  NOT NULL,
  ERROR_VIOLATION   BIT(1) NOT NULL,
  LATENCY_VIOLATION BIT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (START_TIME, APPLICATION_ID, ENTRY_POINT, USER_ID)
)
```

What I'd like to achieve is a summary as follow: per each entry_point I'd like to see how many unique users and how many of them had errors and latency problems.

For example:

```
ENTRY_POINT | TOTAL_USERS | TOTAL_ERRORS | TOTAL_LATENCY
page1       | 2           | 2            | 1
page2       | 1           | 1            | 1
```

I can achieve this goal with this query:

```
SELECT UT.ENTRY_POINT, COUNT(USER_ID) AS TOTAL_USERS, SUM(EXP_ERRORS) AS TOTAL_ERRORS, SUM(EXP_LATENCY) AS TOTAL_LATENCY
FROM (
    SELECT ENTRY_POINT, USER_ID,
    BIT_OR(ERROR_VIOLATION) AS EXP_ERRORS,
    BIT_OR(LATENCY_VIOLATION) AS EXP_LATENCY
    FROM user_transactions
    GROUP BY ENTRY_POINT, USER_ID
) AS UT
GROUP BY UT.ENTRY_POINT;
```

The nested query is using to summarize if users have experienced errors or latency problems, but on a table with lots of data I have performance issues.

My question is how can I optimize this query to avoid the usage of the inner sub-query?

Comment: Your query seems pretty much like the optimum to me. Since you have to process all rows, lots of data are going to be expensive, no matter what. You could work with a materialized view if the underlying data isn't changing too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`.  Here is one way to write the query:

```
SELECT ENTRY_POINT, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID),
       SUM(ERROR_VIOLATION > 0) AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
       SUM(LATENCY_VIOLATION > 0) AS TOTAL_LATENCY
FROM user_transactions
GROUP BY ENTRY_POINT;
```

If you want *users* with errors instead of total errors:

```
SELECT ENTRY_POINT, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID),
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ERROR_VIOLATION > 0 THEN USER_ID END) AS TOTAL_ERRORS,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LATENCY_VIOLATION > 0 THEN USER_ID END) AS TOTAL_LATENCY
FROM user_transactions
GROUP BY ENTRY_POINT;
```

Comment: The second, not the first. But is this going to be faster?

Comment: The 2nd one is it. It's equivalent and about 20% faster. Thanks Gordon. The 1st query is wrong and should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

can't you just use something like:

```
SELECT
    ENTRY_POINT
        ,COUNT(USER_ID) AS TOTAL_USERS
        ,SUM(EXP_ERRORS) AS TOTAL_ERRORS
        ,SUM(EXP_LATENCY) AS TOTAL_LATENCY
    FROM user_transactions
    GROUP BY ENTRY_POINT
```

Comment: This is in no way equivalent.

Comment: Erwin is right. That wouldn't sum the errors per each user.